# Can we re-add the options to add word, excel, power-point documents directly inside our document libraries after adding custom content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration

We have added many document libraries inside our SharePoint online communication site collection >> and for all the document libraries we have defined a custom content type >> but after adding the custom content type the New menu stop showing the options to directly add word, excel, power point documents , as follow:-

[image]

Now i can click on "Edit New Menu " >> then re-add the missing options as follow:-

[image]

so is this recommended ? or will it cause any harm if we re-add those options?

Comment: It won't cause any problem. SharePoint gives you the flexibility to choose menu options in SharePoint library.

Comment: @ShanthaKumarThambidurai but why it will remove those options once we set a custom content type on the document library?